# Sitecore with SolrCloud switch on rebuild

Tags: sitecore, solrcloud

We have recently implemented SolrCloud with Sitecore 8.0 Update 2. All works fine and good with this setup. Then we introduced patch 449298 into the mix to enable switch on rebuild functionality. Our CM server is the only one that initiates indexing. Both CM and CD use searching functionality against SolrCloud.

All works well and fine in regards to incremental updates. But when we rebuild the indexes, the CD servers do not pick up the rebuilt indexes. They still point to the previous "primary" indexes. CM works fine without issues. When we manually switch the indexes then they work fine for CDs as well.

The only issue we ever notice is pasted below but this seems like a harmless error.

```
9/11/2016, 11:48:55 AM  WARN    OverseerCollectionProcessor OverseerCollectionProcessor.processMessage : createalias , {
OverseerCollectionProcessor.processMessage : createalias , {
  "operation":"createalias",
  "name":"social_messages_web_alias_secondary",
  "collections":"social_messages_web_secondary"}
```

Is 449298 required on CDs or can we just OOTB libraries on CDs and 449298 on CM?

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the documentation on the release page in [github](https://github.com/SitecoreSupport/Sitecore.Support.449298/releases) it says the following:

- Download the Sitecore.Support.449298-7.2.6.0.zip file.
- Extract the archive to the Website folder of **all Sitecore** instances in the solution, overwrite existing files if any conflicts occur

So, i think you should apply it on all of Sitecore instances that you have in your environment, I have not tested this myself, But based on the documentation it seems thats the right way.